# Android-How to set Notify CursorAdapter with ListView inside onItemLongClickListener()

Tags: android, listview, android-cursoradapter, notifydatasetchanged, onitemlongclicklistener

I am trying to remove long pressed item from my ListView, populated by a cursor adapter, item is removed but adapter is not notified.

I have read this:

[How to notifyDataSetChange() from onitemclick() method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7334833/how-to-notifydatasetchange-from-onitemclick-method)

and that solution may worked for the the subclass of an ArrayAdapter, but my one extends CursorAdapter,

[cant resolve method: notifyDataSetChanged()](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y7rkY.png) (while trying to solve using the answer of that question)

Code inside notifyDataSetChanged():

```
 notesListView.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {


                Log.d(TAG, "onItemLongClick: " + position + " id: 0" + id);

                List<String> taskList = dbhelper.getTaskList(userName);

                Log.d(TAG, "onItemLongClick: " + taskList);

                dbhelper.deleteTask(userName, taskList.get(position));


                taskList.remove(position);

                cursorAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();


            //    ListAdapter adapter = notesListView.getAdapter();

            //    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();  can't resolve method
```

Another thing is every time user long pressed on an item, a `List<String>` is retrieved from database, and removed it from the `position` it was pressed.

Where I am doing wrong? I also need a decent way of removing item from database which is selected, thanks in advance!

**Edit:**

Here are codes of my adapter:

```
public class MyCursorAdapter extends CursorAdapter {

private LayoutInflater inflater;

public MyCursorAdapter(Context context, Cursor c) {
    super(context, c);

}

@Override
public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {

    inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_cursor, parent, false);

    return view;
}

@Override
public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {

    TextView titleTextView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.list_title);

    TextView detailsTextView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.list_details);

    String titleString = null;
    String detailsString = null;
    try {
        titleString = cursor.getString(1);
        detailsString = cursor.getString(2);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.d("TAG", "Exception on: " + e.toString());
    }

    titleTextView.setText(titleString);
    detailsTextView.setText(detailsString);


}
```

}

Comment: Can you post you complete code for your custom CursorAdapter?

Comment: yeah sure, I can

Comment: I just viewed the source code for CursorAdapter and there is in fact a public method called 'notifyDataSetChanged()'.

Comment: As @WadeWilson  said we have method notifyDataSetChanged() in CursorAdapter class so we should make the conversion from ListAdapter to Cursor adapter to use it.

Comment: It looks like you are not actually updating the cursor. You could either switch to an ArrayAdapter based on your taskList or you could requery the database after making the changes and swap the cursor in the cursor adapter.